# Tiny REST API for making CRUD operations on list of posts

Tags: node.js, api, express.js

This is not a question related to a bug.I've just created a very tiny `node.js/express API` for education purposes.
I've created a very little `API` and what i would like is to have your point of view about the design and projet architecture and what you would recommand be as advice in term of what i can improve in this code.

As it's open sources you're also welcome for `pull requests`.

Notice : I've not considered aspects like `logging`,`ORM's` or specific packages for `validation` or these kind of things.

Here is the github repo where i explain cleary how to run the project in the local computer.

https://github.com/jochri3/tiny-express-api

My code organization is in a MVC pattern:

```
|controllers
    -posts.js
|middlewares
    -bodyValidation.js
    -postExists.js
|models
    -post.js
|startups
    -db.js
    -routes.js
app.js
router.js
```

Here is the codes content:

**controllers/posts.js**

```
const Post=require('../models/post');

const index=async(req,res)=>{
    const posts=await Post.getAll();
    res.send({data:posts})
}

// const show=(req,res)=>{
    
// }

const create=async({body},res)=>{
    await Post.create(body);
    res.status(201).send({message:'post created successfully'});
}

const update=async({body,params:{id}},res)=>{
    await Post.update(id,body)
    res.status(201).send({message:'posts updated successfully'});
}

const destroy=async({params:{id}},res)=>{
    await Post.delete(id);
     res.status(202).send({message:'post deleted successfully'})
}

module.exports={
    index,
    // show,
    create,
    update,
    destroy
}
```

**middlewares/bodyValidate**

```
module.exports=async({body},res,next)=>{
    const bodyValues=Object.values(body);
    if(bodyValues.some(value=>!value)){
        return res.status(422).send({message:'Veuillez remplir tous les champs correctement'})
    }
    next();
}
```

**middlewares/postExists.js**

```
const connection=require("../startups/db")

module.exports=async(req,res,next)=>{
    const {params:{id}}=req;
    if(!id){
        return res.status(404).send({message:'not found'})
    }
    const post=await connection.select().from('posts').where('id',id);
    if(!post.length){
        return res.status(404).send({message:'not found'})
    }
    req.post=post;
    next();
}
```

**models/post.js**

```
const connection=require("../startups/db");

class Post{
    
    static getAll(){
        return connection.select().from("posts");
    }

    static update(id,data){
        return connection('posts').where('id',id).update(data);
    }

    // static getOne(id){

    // }

    static delete(id){
        return connection('posts').where('id', id).del();
    }

    static create(data){
        return connection('posts').insert(data);
    }
}

module.exports=Post;
```

**startups/db.js**

```
const knex=require("knex");


module.exports=knex({
    client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: "./db.sqlite"
  }
})
```

**startups/routes.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const {postsRouter}=require('../router')

module.exports=(app)=>{
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use('/api/posts',postsRouter)
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const connection=require("./startups/db");

const app=express();

require('./startups/routes')(app,connection)

require('express-async-errors');

const port=8000

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.info(`Server in listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**router.js**

```
const express=require('express');

//custom middlewares
const idExists=require("./middlewares/postsExists");
const bodyValidates=require("./middlewares/bodyValidate");

const PostsController=require("./controllers/posts")


const postsRouter=express.Router();


postsRouter.get('/',PostsController.index);

postsRouter.get('/:id',[idExists],async(req,res)=>{
        res.send({data:req.post[0]});
    });

postsRouter.post('/',[bodyValidates],PostsController.create)

postsRouter.put('/:id',[idExists,bodyValidates],PostsController.update)

postsRouter.delete('/:id',[idExists],PostsController.destroy)

module.exports={
    postsRouter
}
```

You can view the project in codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-montalcini-vsbfb